# One strong variable load on components in principal component analysis?

Tags: pca, interpretation

Hello and good day to you. I am using Principle Component Analysis (PCA) with Varimax rotation to analyze variables on my research.

There are 20 variables and 6 components were extracted. From the result, I noticed that the variables were strongly loaded on one component.

And I attached the Rotated component Matrix which I got from the PCA analysis.

As you can see from the picture there were 10 different variables which put into the first component

I don't know where did I makes mistakes of where the fault is coming from, can anybody please give me a suggestion? Thank You.

[image: Rotating Component Matrix]

Comment: Why is that a mistake?

Comment: What is your goal in using PCA? And are your variables measured without error?

Comment: Thats my question, is it a problem when many factors were group into only one strong dimension. My goal using PCA was for grouping the 20 factors into different component dimensions

Answer (score 3):

There's no indication that there's any mistake here. PCA is a dimension reduction technique, so it will find orthogonal vectors. If you have many correlated variables, it's not surprising that many of them will be strongly loaded onto a single dimension.

It might be worth your time to read [our most-upvoted thread on CV, which has many great explanations of what PCA is and how it works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues).